# convert json string object to integer in ng-view

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to convert json object to integer in ng-view:

json string:

```
$scope.json_arr = [{
                    'id': '1',
                    'name': 'abc'
                },
                {
                    'id': '2',
                    'name': 'xyz'
                }];
```

in view:

```
<ul ng-repeat="vals in json_arr">
    <li><input type="number" ng-model="vals.id" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" ng-model="vals.name" /></li>
</ul>
```

when i see the ouput, the `number` field is coming blank as the `value` of the `id` object is string.

How do i convert string `'id':'1'` to integer??

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BDFRsas8h5DsMNvK1V1m?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-init`, this will run whenever a new element in the array appears for `ng-repeat`, if you use it like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="vals in json_arr" ng-init="parseId(vals)">
    <li><input type="number" ng-model="vals.id" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" ng-model="vals.name" /></li>
</ul>
```

Then all that's left is to write the `parseId` function referenced

```
  $scope.parseId = function(val){
    val.id = parseInt(val.id);
  }
```

**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3iYezrBKIcxKErbyzF7p?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

try it

Html side

```
<ul ng-repeat="vals in json_arr">
    <li> <input type="number" value="{{convertToInt(vals.id)}}"/></li>
    <li><input type="text" ng-model="vals.name" /> </li>
</ul>
```

Js Side

```
$scope.convertToInt= function (value) {
            return parseInt(value);
        };
```

It's working  for me.

[Working Source code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/S9coDaJyyjKhKbzQhP42?p=preview)

Comment: how do i use `value` , it should be `ng-model` right?

Comment: But you can define the `ng-model` in this  other type of way `{{property name}}  ` .. It is same as you defined `ng-model="vals.id"` .

Comment: can you please create OR update my plunker so that i can get a clear picture because i've tried your code, but didn't worked for me :(

Comment: I have posted new plunker link . @Jay Please take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/S9coDaJyyjKhKbzQhP42?p=preview

Comment: yeah thats correct but when i write `ng-model="vals.id"` its not working, and without `ng-model` how do i bind textbox value current scope??

Comment: hey you don't need `ng-model="vals.id"` man.  `value="{{vals.id}}"` and ng-model="vals.id"  are same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55706/discussion-between-jay-and-user256103).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular form to store one or more variable values and pass a request for api post or put method,
example:

```
component.ts file

    `loginForm: FormGroup;
     mockService: ServiceName;
     
         this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          Id: [''],
          empID: [''],
          roomID: ['']      
        });
           this.loginForm.get('Id').setValue(parseInt(this.Id));
    this.loginForm.get('empID').setValue(parseInt(this.empID));      
     this.loginForm.get('roomID').setValue(parseInt(this.roomID));
    
let request = JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value);

this.mockloginService.loginValuesCheckmethod(request).subscribe((response) => {
      if (response.isSuccess && response.responseCode === '200') {}
```

This will pass payload value as int